# String vs Integer

Tags: sqlite

I am having a bit of a dilemma, I have a huge non-relational sqlite database with a table containing millions of entries with relations between entities using their "ID"(A long number). Now, these entries create multiple hierarchies. What I want to do is store the data for each hierarchy separately and playing around with temporary tables and indexes I started to wonder if there is any difference on doing an index of a number as string or integer.

In fewer words, does the index of "43789164238" as a string work faster than the same number as an integer?

Comment: My guess would be that an integer might be slightly faster because it needs less storage than a long string - less storage means less IO means more speed....

Comment: Integers are faster to compare and take less space than strings. And with the way normal sqlite tables work, an [INTEGER PRIMARY KEY](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid) column will be the fastest way to look up a row in a table - roughly twice as fast as looking up a different indexed column (unless it's a covering index)

Comment: Useful reading: https://www.sqlite.org/queryplanner.html

Answer (score 2):

Integers are faster than strings. The reason for this is quite simple. An integer uses less space than a string.

- integer is between 2 and 8 bytes
- a string is at least 4 bytes plus the value inside

hope this helps :)

Comment: Yeah, that string would only have a one byte type/length field in that rows storage (and 11 bytes of data). Still bigger than an integer, and slower to compare, of course.

Comment: But does sqlite operate with strings and integers the same way?

Comment: @AlexandruMartalogu YES! The reason for this is simple, an INTEGER uses less space than a STRING even SQLITE uses this and is therefore faster.